# h.264 Hardware Encoding with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I must capture h.264 raw stream in Linux from a UVC USB camera with Sonix SN9C291B h.264 hardware encoder, maybe the most used camera controller encoder.
Now, I only found sample code to capture stream using `avformat_open_input` with `/dev/video0` or `/dev/video1` function but it does not work.
What is the ffmpeg function I must use to capture h.264 raw data from the camera?

After call the function:

```
 c = avcodec_alloc_context3 (codec);

 c->bit_rate = 400000;

 c->width = 640; this setting generate an error! Why?
```